# CSS Cannot select div, but can select h1

Tags: html, css

Here's my problem. I can select h1, h4, p, body, all that stuff, but when I try to select the specific h1 in a div titled "a" I get the good old nothing.

```
<style type="text/css">
.a h1 {
color: #6495ED;
}
</style>
<body>
<div style="a">
<h1>Hi</h1>
</div>
```

The text appears, but no color 6495ED, the one I want.

Comment: Change the `style` attribute to a `class` attribute.. `style="a"` -> `class="a"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your CSS `.a h1`, you're trying to select the h1 inside a class named 'a'. In your HTML, there is no class 'a'.

Change

```
<div style="a">
```

to

```
<div class="a">
```

Comment: Oh, sorry! Beginner mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`<div style="a">` is not the proper way to invoke the `.a h1` css.. You should use `<div class="a">` since `.a` is a class identifier for css's..

Answer (score -1):

You should also give the div a class so you can point to in within your css otherwise your just trying to style nothing specific